# Basic javascript ; alert on click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Trying to teach myself how to use js in rails and I found a good video on the topic but somehow it does not work for me and I can not figure out why.

app/views/static_pages/help.html.erb:

```
...
<p><%= link_to "Description", "#", id: "desc-link" %></p>
...
```

app/javascripts/static_pages.coffee:

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
    $("#desc-link").click ->
        alert "Done!"
```

If I click on the link, nothing happens (no error either).

Comment: Did youve loaded jquery?

Comment: Do you mean the "//= require jquery" line in application.js? If so, then yes.

Comment: @Bubibob: Load the jquey & use $(document).on "ready" instead of page:load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails 5.

I restarted server after add require jquery

my working code

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ->
    $("#desc-link").click ->
        alert("Done!")
      )
```

or

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ->
    $("#desc-link").on 'click', ->
        alert("Done!")
      )
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Any idea though why the others did not? Is it due to the fact that i use rails 5?

Comment: In rails 5 you have turbolinks (5 in this case). So javascript should be fired after page is load. Event: 'turbolinks:load'. If you fire javascript immediately DOM don't have any objects. Please read [documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) of turbolinks. In rails pages are load via AJAX not reload, so DOM is asynchronously load.

Comment: What's more `$(document).ready ->` is run only in first page load and every `F5` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready ->
   $('#desc-link').on 'click', ->
      alert 'Done!'
      return
   return
```